# Hello World Example for Parallel Computing:

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I'm new to parallel computing and am running into problems with server/client connections.  I am running C++ code http://code.google.com/p/rockstar/ on my school's cluster and am not having any luck beyond the compiling.  I am receiving various communication errors between the server and client nodes.

In any case, I was wondering if anybody has a good, simple example of a program that I could run on the cluster or on xcode to test whether the problem lies within the code I'm trying to run or the cluster, itself.

Also, is an environment such as XCode capable of running a parallel job on it's own (to test hello world) or is an add on required?

Thanks for your help, (I've been searching for a solution for a while, but can't find any understandable explanations thus far).

Tyler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any addons. Just link with pthread, and start playing with the thread apis. I'd start with just trying to spawn some threads and joining them. Then I'd learn about mutexes.

I posted some threading classes that I use here: http://oroboro.com/portable-threads-and-Mutexes

Comment: +1 Nice overview - looks very comprehensive - thanks for sharing!